# How can I tell if power supply output is DC or AC?

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc

I am using a [Koheron SPS100 power supply](https://www.koheron.com/photonics/sps100-quad-channel-adjustable-power-supply) and wondering wether it outputs DC or AC voltage. I also have a Klein Tools MM400 multimeter but I am fairly new to electrical engineering. How can I tell whether I should be probing with the AC or DC setting?

Comment: it says "positive and negative rails". That only exists in DC. Honestly "I'm new to electrical engineering" still means you should be able to investigate that much about what "DC" and "AC" are.

Comment: *whether I should be probing with the AC or DC setting?* You can use a modern digital multimeter to measure AC in DC mode, or measure DC in AC mode.  Normally, if you use AC mode to measure a DC voltage, you should see 0 V (or a small voltage caused by the ripple). If you use DC mode to measure a AC voltage, you should see 0 V (or a voltage indicates its DC offset). If you use AC mode to measure AC, or DC mode to measure DC, you should see the expected voltage. Try doing it by yourself, so you can learn how a meter is used, and how to determine whether the voltage is DC or AC.

Answer (score 2):

You won't harm the multimeter if you are in the wrong voltage mode. Not all multimeters will read a DC voltage when used in AC mode and they will give fluctuating readings when you measure an AC voltage in DC mode.

The device you linked to appears to have DC outputs.

But: don't mix up current and voltage mode and the respective connectors of the multimeter, that would be harmful!

Comment: Hi, Regarding: "*The multimeter won't read a DC voltage when used in AC mode*" FYI that statement does not seem to be universally true. Please see [this previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/101418/101852), where at least 2 multimeters *did* display a voltage on their AC volts range, when a DC voltage was being measured.

Answer (score 1):

That's a DC power supply so it outputs DC. Use the multimeter with DC setting.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked says "3 positive and 1 negative rails", so it must be DC.