# Double voltage in full wave rectifier

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, diodes, multimeter, rectifier

I made a simple full wave rectifier using a center tapped transformer and 2 1N4007 diodes.

The DC output is around 14 volts but when I connect a 100uF capacitor with the output leads of the DC output, I get around around 21 volts DC and 44 volts AC.

Without the capacitor it works as expected but with the capacitor why is this the case?

[image]

Comment: With the smoothing capacitor present, and no load, you get the peak voltage on the output. Without it you measure the RMS voltage of the rectified sine.

Comment: So it means the actual peak of the pulsating dc is around 21 volts?

Comment: Yes, peak = RMS * sqrt(2).

Comment: And what about the ac voltage why is it 44V?

Comment: Not a clue, there shouldn't be any AC on the output. Is this a real circuit or simulator?

Comment: Its a real circuit, without the capacitor it shows 0 volts ac as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115949/discussion-between-shahroze-shahab-and-unimportant).

Comment: Get your meter, set it to AC volts and measure the voltage across a battery. Report back with the voltage you measure or try and figure out why your meter set to AC can measure many volts of AC across a battery.

Comment: Yes its reporting, but why is it so? I am totally confused? Its reporting around 20v across a 9v battery.

Comment: Please read https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101418/measuring-ac-voltage-from-dc-battery

Comment: Ok so the multimeter measures the average which is 9V and so to get the peak value as of it were AC it multiplies it by $\pi$ then divides by $\sqrt 2$ to get te RMS value of around 20V. Am i right?