# Is the LED driver output voltage AC or DC?

Tags: led, driver

My LED driver output voltage is 150VDC:

[image]

It is also 322VAC:

[image]

I checked it with two multimeters.

The input voltage is 237VAC.

Comment: Read @Andyaka 's answer here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/101418/measuring-ac-voltage-from-dc-battery

Comment: Cannot assume voltages will be correct with no load attached.  Can only measure with LEDs lit.

Comment: Your multimeter is also shouting to change the battery. Low battery can be one reason for weird measurements.

Answer (score 3):

Some inexpensive DVMs give an invalid high reading when set to measure AC volts but are actually have a DC voltage applied.

Try measuring a 9 volt battery with the meter set to AC volts.

Answer (score 2):

Your meter does not measure the true RMS value of the voltage when you put it in the AC voltage mode.

Instead, it probably measures the **average** voltage and estimates what the RMS value would be if the input is actual an AC sine wave. Many low-cost meters do this.

If you really want to see what the output looks like, use an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 0):

if you put your multimeter in AC to measure DC it will read something wrong...

The instrument is reading the DC value as a RMS of a greater value.